Duda con un error en un analizador lexico en python
Buenas este proyecto es un analizador léxico básico de interfaz que al colocar un código en un cuadro de texto, lo acomoda en una tabla, el problema es que coloque una forma de que detecte errores, en caso de que se ponga un identificador que inicie con un número, que un identificador tenga un valor asignado y la longitud mostrara una ventana mencionando el error. Pero al colocar ejemplos para eso este ignora los id con números al inicio y a veces se confunde con id que, si tiene valores, según esta correcto, pero soy aun novato en Python.Gracias.
Aquí un poco del codigo:
def procesar_expresion(resultado, expresion):
    # Validar si la entrada esta vacia y pues error 
    if not expresion.strip():
        mostrar_error("Error: No hay nada escrito.")
        return
    
    # Expresiones regulares para los operadores, identificadores, números, comentarios y cadenas
    exp_operadores_matematicos = r'[+\-*/]'
    exp_operadores_logicos = r'[<>]=?!=|==|\(|\)|<|>|<=|>=|&&|\|\|'
    exp_numeros = r'\b\d+\b'
    exp_identificadores = r'(?![\d])\b[a-zA-Z_]\w*'
    exp_comentarios = r'//.*|/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|#.*'
    exp_cadenas = r'"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"'
    expresiones_total = '|'.join([exp_operadores_matematicos, exp_operadores_logicos, exp_numeros, exp_identificadores, exp_cadenas])
    tokens = re.findall(expresiones_total, re.sub(exp_comentarios, '', expresion))

    descripcion_tokens = []
    identificadores = []

    # Iterar sobre los tokens y categorizarlos
    for token in tokens:
        # Determinar si es una palabra reservada
        reservada = "Sí" if token in palabras_reservadas else "No"
        if token in nombres_operadores_matematicos:
            descripcion_tokens.append(('OP_ARIT', token, nombres_operadores_matematicos[token], reservada))
        elif token in nombres_operadores_logicos:
            descripcion_tokens.append(('OP_LOG', token, nombres_operadores_logicos[token], reservada))
        elif token.isdigit():
            descripcion_tokens.append(('NUM', token, 'Digitos', reservada))
        elif token in nombre_funciones:  # Añadido para detectar funciones
            descripcion_tokens.append(('FUNC', token, 'Función', reservada))
        elif token in palabras_reservadas:
            descripcion_tokens.append(('PALA_RES', token, 'Palabra reservada', reservada))
        elif token.startswith('"') and token.endswith('"'):
            descripcion_tokens.append(('CADENA', token, 'Cadena de digitos y numeros', reservada))
        else:
            
            if not token[0].isdigit():  
                if token not in identificadores:
                    identificadores.append(token)
                    
                    if expresion.count(token) == 1:
                        mostrar_error(f"Error: El identificador '{token}' no tiene un valor asignado.")
                        return
                    
                    if len(token) > 30:
                        mostrar_error(f"Error: El identificador '{token}' tiene una longitud mayor a 30 caracteres.")
                        return
                descripcion_tokens.append(('ID', token, 'ID Letras con digitos', reservada))
            else:
                mostrar_error(f"Error: El identificador '{token}' no puede comenzar con un número.")
                return
            
    resultado.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
    resultado.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    resultado.insert(tk.END, "{:<10} {:<40} {:<30} {:<10}\n".format('Token', 'Lexema', 'Patrón', 'Reservada'))
    resultado.insert(tk.END, "-"*100 + "\n")
    for token, lexema, patron, reservada in descripcion_tokens:
        resultado.insert(tk.END, "{:<10} {:<40} {:35} {:<10}\n".format(token, lexema, patron, reservada))
    resultado.config(state=tk.DISABLED)


Las expresiones regulares no reconocen expresiones recursivas (anidadas) como ((1 + 2)). Lo más simple es usar un parser recursivo descendente https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser
